# Ros serial protokoll white Microcontroller

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

im using ros and it works fine. But now i will send data from AVR Microcontroller to ros. i dont use any arduino board so what is the protokoll to send data via serial port? for example to transmitt odometry data. something like that

odom/term/x/y/z/r

is this possible without rosserial_arduino?

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40672/ros-serial-protokoll-white-microcontroller/) by [roster](https://answers.ros.org/users/2983/roster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is also "regular" [rosserial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosserial), along with a (generic?) rosserial_client. On the other hand, an Arduino is just an AVR microcontroller on a standard breakout board.
The rosserial page also lists the general protocol, but you'll need the node running to act as a bridge between ROS and the serial connection.

---

Originally posted by [rlinsalata](https://answers.ros.org/users/2578/rlinsalata/) with karma: 271 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0